# How to install the Latest Stable Docker Version on Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, windows-server-2016

Running the following powershell commands only sees 17.03.2-ee-5 as the latest:

```
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider -Verbose -Update
```

However looking at docker documentation 17.06 is stable.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/windows/docker-ee/#use-a-script-to-install-docker-ee
https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-windows-server-2016-without-desktop-experience/34071/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command listed does work the version just hadn't released to ee yet.